# How to programatically check currently set theme in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I want to check if the user has set a light or dark theme. Is it possible to do so programmatically in Windows Phone 8.1 (store app).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff769545(v=vs.105).aspx) you will find sample codes, which you can use to determine the current theme - by comparing resources. For example:

```
private bool IsDarkTheme()
{ return (double)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeOpacity"] > 0; }
```

But - I've enocuntered some problems running the above line at WP8.1 Runtime - it couldn't find the requested key. As it turned out - the above code will work [only on WP8.1 Silverlight (also WP8.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/ff769552(v=vs.105).aspx).

But (again), nothing stands on your way [to define your own *ThemeResource*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.resourcedictionary.themedictionaries) and check it's state:

In app.xaml - define some *ThemeResources*:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <x:Boolean x:Key="IsDarkTheme">false</x:Boolean>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <x:Boolean x:Key="IsDarkTheme">true</x:Boolean>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                <x:Boolean x:Key="IsDarkTheme">false</x:Boolean>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then you can use for example a property in your code:

```
public bool IsDarkTheme { get { return (bool)Application.Current.Resources["IsDarkTheme"]; } }
```

Note also that in some cases you may need to check for *HighContrast* - according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868165(v=win.10).aspx), you can do it by checking [AccessibilitySettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.viewmanagement.accessibilitysettings.aspx) or extend your own created *ThemeResource* by *HighContrast values*.

Answer (score 5):

To check which theme is active you can use RequestedTheme property of the Application object [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme.aspx)

```
var isDark = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark;
```