# How can I detect Windows 10 light/dark mode?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm using `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings` to get system accent color but it seems this class does not have any method or property for light/dark mode. I failed to find a document for this feature, how can I detect this?

PS: I'm making a JS app which does not have access for `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found an easier solution, which should work in JavaScript apps as well, without requiring the Windows Runtime Component - the [`UISettings` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings):

```
var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
var color = uiSettings.getColorValue(
                        Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.background
                       );
```

The color you get is either **black** for **dark** theme or **white** for **light** theme.

The class also has very useful event `ColorValuesChanged` which you can use to [observe theme changes at runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.colorvalueschanged).

Comment: How would this work in JavaScript? I.e. using `wscript` from the command line?

Answer (score 18):

You can create a Windows Runtime Component project in your solution from there you access `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace. Add a method to check current ApplicationTheme like that.

```
public sealed class Test
{
    public static string CurrentTheme()
    {
        var isDark = Application.Current.RequestedTheme == ApplicationTheme.Dark;

        if (isDark)
            return "Dark";

        return "Light";
    }
}
```

Add reference to windows runtime component project in your javascript app project and you can call this method where ever you want to check application theme. Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript) for walkthrough on createing Windows Runtime Component.

Answer (score 15):

For Windows 10, the value of the `AppsUseLightTheme` property in the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize` of the registry specifies wherever Windows is in dark or light mode.

Comment: AppsUseLightTheme (REG_DWORD): 0 = Dark mode, 1 = Light mode

Comment: Be aware that the `AppsUseLightTheme` value might be missing completely. In this case, you should fall back to a light mode. (Happened to me on an older Windows 10 system; the one that comes with the IE Test VM images from Microsoft itself).

Answer (score 4):

You can read the registry if the theme is enabled for the current user and get the setting from there. Something like this...

```
private const string RegistryKeyPath = @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize";

private const string RegistryValueName = "AppsUseLightTheme";

private static ApplicationTheme GetWindowsTheme()
{
    using var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(RegistryKeyPath);
    var registryValueObject = key?.GetValue(RegistryValueName);
    if (registryValueObject == null)
    {
        return ApplicationTheme.Light;
    }
    var registryValue = (int)registryValueObject;

    return registryValue > 0 ? ApplicationTheme.Light : ApplicationTheme.Dark;
}
```

Full example can be found in this link
https://engy.us/blog/2018/10/20/dark-theme-in-wpf/

Answer (score 3):

Before the Windows Anniversary update you could not do that. The application theme was always the one you set in the `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application
  ...
  RequestedTheme="Dark">
</Application>
```

Now with the new Anniversary Update, you can remove this line from the `App.xaml` file, which will make the app honor the user's system settings.

The `RequestedTheme` enumeration has actually three values - `Dark`, `Light` and `Default`. `Default` is the value that reflects the system settings, `Dark` and `Light` force the theme.

If you want to actually detect the current theme in code when App's `RequestedTheme` is `Default`, you will probably need to check the some color resource like [`SystemAltHighColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources) for its value, because that will give you an idea of what theme is currently set.

Comment: I need a solution that also works for HTML but this one sadly seems to work only on XAML apps.

Answer (score 0):

*ThemeResources* have been introduced in 8.1 and their behavior is similar in W10. Therefore you can define suitable resource in *ThemeDictionaries* responsible for available *Themes* and then you can check the defined resource when you whant to know which *Theme* is currently used.

The code will be very similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24845631/2681948).

Comment: It seems the solution is only for XAML apps. No solution for HTML apps?

Comment: @KagamiSaschaRosylight I've not played with HTML much for now, but maybe you can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Value in PowerShell you can use the following code:

```
(New-Object Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings).GetColorValue("background")
```