# Is there a way to detect whether Mac OS or Windows OS is in Dark Mode in Java

Tags: java, javafx

Currently I am developing an application, However I am unaware of any methods to check if the system is in dark mode already.The application is made with JavaFX on a Mac. Currently I have a CheckMenuItem which when checked, loads up with the use of an IF statement a 'darkmode.css' file. And removes it if the file if the checkmenuitem box is unchecked.

However instead of a check MenuItem I want to be able to activate the css file when the OS is in darkmode and when its not for it to remove it again. I feel like that Java may not be able to do this. If there is any ways for this to be done I will be keen on learning and interested on how you may have implemented it.

In a nutshell native dark mode almost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard Java API for finding out whether the host's native UI is in "dark mode" or "night mode" .

In UI design terms, "dark mode" is a relatively new idea.  From what I can tell, it only really took off as an idea in 2018; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-on-dark_color_scheme.  This was well after both Swing and JavaFX had stabilized.  (In the case of Swing, decades after!)

There is a recent (December 2019) RFE in the OpenJDK Bug tracker for detecting the host OS's dark mode setting: [JDK-8235460](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8235460)

In the absence of standard Java APIs, you could try OS specific ideas; e.g. as described in the following:

- [How can I detect Windows 10 light/dark mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734615/how-can-i-detect-windows-10-light-dark-mode)
- [How to detect if OS X is in dark mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207077/how-to-detect-if-os-x-is-in-dark-mode)

For Android dark / night mode detection is supported:

- [Android - How to detect if night mode is on when using AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_AUTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170028/android-how-to-detect-if-night-mode-is-on-when-using-appcompatdelegate-mode-ni)

Comment: Thats a shame that it doesn't support it.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there are multiple ways to achieve this. [Intellij Idea](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) itself is written in Java, and she has an os theme synchronization functionality since version `2020.3`.

You can use a [library](https://github.com/Dansoftowner/jSystemThemeDetector) called `jSystemThemeDetector`. You have the ability to detect dark mode with it on **Windows 10**, **MacOS** and even on some **Linux distributions**.

Simple detection example:

```java
final OsThemeDetector detector = OsThemeDetector.getDetector();
final boolean isDarkThemeUsed = detector.isDark();
if (isDarkThemeUsed) {
    //The OS uses a dark theme
} else {
    //The OS uses a light theme
}
```

Synchronization example:

```java
final OsThemeDetector detector = OsThemeDetector.getDetector();
detector.registerListener(isDark -> {
    if (isDark) {
        //The OS switched to a dark theme
    } else {
        //The OS switched to a light theme
    }
});
```